# What will happen when open files reached limit?

Tags: linux

The **ulimit** option of **open files** is set at 100000.
when accept() 100000 connections, what will happen? Are the accepted connections closed by os?

Comment: You would not expect established connections to fail because of this, but new ones will not be accepted.  However, behind the scenes, nothing which serves those open connections will be able to open any new file handles, either, so it is likely that it will fail unless you have taken extreme care to handle this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It will return -1 and set errno to EMFILE. Please see the man page for more info:http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html

Comment: and is there any other unexpected effect from kernel?

Comment: Obviously, anything else (e.g. any other system call) in your process needing a file descriptor will fail for the same reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "unexpected" anyway?

Comment: e.g. it can't accept any new connection even if open fd number is decrease. it happened in my program.